# How to Select a Specific Element in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

In `Selenium` we are able to select an entire page (by stimulating the keys `Ctrl + a`) using:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(XPath));
element.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a"));
```

This causes Selenium to select the entire page.

I'm trying to select only the contents of a specific web element. For example, if my XPath locates the title of a web page I want to be able to select just the title and not the entire page.

How can this be done?

Note: My goal is to combine this with: `Actions(driver).moveByOffset(location.x, location.y);`. First, I want to move the cursor/mouse to a element with the given coordinates (using the method `moveByOffset()`) and then I want to select the contents of that element (but not the entire page)..

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You can just get text content of element with `getText()` or if you want just to highlight element you can change it `style`

Comment: @Andersson Bec I want to be able to scrape (or select) element text using only the x and y coordinates of the element

Answer (score 0):

Set the focus to the element first, assuming that it can receive focus:

```
element.sendKeys("");
```

then the second sendKeys should send the characters to that element specifically.

Comment: This does not answer the question.